# Does the Torah mention infanticide?

Tags: torah-study

infanticide (killing or abandon ones newborn) was extremely popular in the ancient world. The Torah clearly & often stresses the worth of human life & emphatically prohibits murder but considering how prevalent this abhorrent custom was then (some believe 15-40% of babies worldwide were killed by their own parents in that era) I wonder if the Torah speaks out against it specifically?

Comment: There is https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.2

Comment: "Some believe 15-40% of babies worldwide were killed by their own parents in that era"?? Sounds like a bogus claim. Do you have a source for that? Cultic infanticide was never that widespread in even one location, let alone globally.

Comment: @mroll also https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.1.16

Comment: Killing for what purpose? Killing babies was mentioned numerous times like someof the other comments point out. But do you call infanticide when they kill for cult worship? Or becausethe Pharoh decreed it? Or because the city was under siege? How about Hevel, he was only one day old when he got killed?

Comment: Genesis 9:6 (as per Sanhedrin 57b), and is codified by Maimonides in his discussion of laws pertaining to Noahides (Hilchot Melachim 9:4).

Comment: @shimon bm Williamson, Laila (1978). "Infanticide: an anthropological analysis". In Kohl, Marvin (ed.). Infanticide and the Value of Life. NY: Prometheus Books. pp. 61–75.

Comment: @Lages - wow! I’m just reading up on this now. Thanks for the information (disgusting as it is). If I can make one note (not necessarily worthy of an edit): “infanticide” might carry connotations of ritual behaviour. From what I’m seeing, Williamson assigns much of this to babies being unwanted (the children of prostitutes, etc). Mostly what people quote from Tanakh concerns the former exclusively (Molekh, and so forth).

Comment: Also, if you’re looking for academic literature, Michael Fishbane has a little that touches on this in his *Biblical Interpretation in Ancient Israel*.